# jQuery not loading in DOM Window

Tags: jquery

All,
I've got the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// more code using $ as alias to jQuery
alert('it works');
},'jQuery');
```

When the page loads I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
```

I've loaded jQuery before I tried to add this.

Here is how this was loaded (my code is the custom.js):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/oml_live_update/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/oml_live_update/wp-content/themes/alyeska/framework/frontend/assets/plugins/prettyphoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js?ver=3.1.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/oml_live_update/wp-content/themes/alyeska/framework/frontend/assets/js/superfish.js?ver=1.4.8'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/oml_live_update/wp-content/themes/alyeska/framework/frontend/assets/js/flexslider.js?ver=1.8'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/oml_live_update/wp-content/themes/alyeska/framework/frontend/assets/js/roundabout.js?ver=1.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/oml_live_update/wp-content/themes/alyeska/assets/js/alyeska.min.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/oml_live_update/wp-content/themes/alyeska/assets/js/custom.js?ver=1.0'></script>
```

Any ideas on why this won't work?

Comment: When are you loading the jquery script before or after this code?

Comment: Have you added jQuery file before this code?

Comment: You are doing something wrong. May be you haven included jquery file. It is working on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DD5jJ/)

Comment: Did you try to check if the first `script` actually loads any code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    alert('it works');
});
```

Does that not work for you? This is a standard syntax for this: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

If you want to create an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression):

```
(function ($) {
    alert('it works');
})(jQuery);
```

This creates a new scope for the code within and passes in the `jQuery` object as `$`.

## Update

I don't use WordPress but my understanding is that `$j=jQuery.noConflict();` is run, so jQuery is basically stored in the `$j` variable (if it isn't done automatically then it needs to be done manually):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/oml_live_update/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
<script>
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function () {
    alert('it works');
});
</script>
...
```

Also note that you can pass `$` into the anonymous function that is the `document.ready` event handler so you don't have to use `$j`:

```
$j(function ($) {
    alert('it works');
    //you can now use $() instead of $j()
});
```

## Update

Have you tried using `jQuery` in place of `$`?

```
jQuery(function($) {
    alert('it works');
    //since `$` was passed into this function, it can be used instead of `jQuery`
});
```

Comment: I'm using it in Wordpress so I'm doing that because of the noConflict that Wordpress has.

Comment: @user1048676 See the **update** to my answer. I don't know if WordPress does the `$.noConflict()` on its own or if you have to.

Comment: @user1048676 Check-out my last **update**. You should just be able to use `jQuery` in place of `$` in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the conflicting versions. Use

```
<script>
    $.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
    alert('it works');
    }); //You dont need to pass the pass the extra 'jQuery' Parameter
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem,

in my case, the superfish menu was working fine, but i would still get this error.

i had

```
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("ul.sf-menu").superfish({ 
            pathClass:  'current' 
        }); 
    });  
</script>
```

and firebug would point to the pathClass.

> ```
> TypeError: $("ul.sf-menu").superfish is not a function
> [Break On This Error]     
>
> pathClass:  'current'
> ```

This may not work for you, but try and remove that entire script call, i.e

```
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("ul.sf-menu").superfish({ 
            pathClass:  'current' 
        }); 
    });  
</script>
```

, it worked for me, still trying to figure out how its reading the menu, but it worked. Firebug wont bug me, IE wont tell me its not secure.